# Python - I am trying to copy and paste below file into my h drive, which is the personal drive

Tags: python, shutil

I am trying to copy and paste a file into my `h:` drive, which is a personal drive. I am getting the following error:

```sh
target = (r'H:\')
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Here is my code :

```py
import shutil

original = (r'H:\Bulk upload\filetocopy.xlsx')
target = (r'H:\')
shutil.copyfile(original,target)
```

Comment: why did you use regex string?

Comment: Hi - i thought that was required for a path. I removed the r before target but still getting the error

Comment: @obayhan There's no  such thing as a 'regex string'. This is called a raw string.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille yes but mostly they used for regexes so thats why i called regex string

Comment: @rbose An easy solution to avoid all escaping problems is to use forward slashes `/`, even in Windows paths. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python . So, `target = ('H:/')`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is ending string literal with backslash in single quotes. You should use `target = ('H:\\')` without the r and with two backslashes. Otherwise you are going to get this type of escape error. If you have the r with two backslashes you will get literally two backslashes.

A second problem (noticed after comment) is that the target is still a directory rather than a valid file path. So you will have to either use `shutil.copy` instead of `shutil.copyfile`, or add the file name to the end of the destination path, in which case there is no escape at the end of the string issue.

Comment: Hi Andrew - I just tried that, but getting this error:                                                              

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'H:\\' . I amended the code to this: ```import shutil

original = (r'H:\Bulk upload\filetocopy.xlsx')
target = ('H:\\')

shutil.copyfile(original,target)```

Comment: Well yeah this is a second error I did not notice. shutil.copyfile expects the destination to be a file. You should use shutil.copy or add the file name to the destination.